# Unable to include a specific gallery in customUI14.xml for Excel

Tags: excel, ribbonx

I am creating a custom ribbon in Excel 2019 using customUI14.xml. I have been able to successfully include galleries in the XML file, some examples are shown below and they reflect successfully in the Excel ribbon.

```
                    <gallery idMso="ThemeEffectsGallery" size="large" />
                    <gallery idMso="ChartColorsGallery" size="large" />
                    <gallery idMso="ThemeColorsGallery" size="large" />
```

However when I try to include the gallery ChartLegend in the XML file using the below line it does not show up in my custom ribbbon in Excel 2019

```
<gallery idMso="ChartLegend" size="large" />
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Try using `control` rather than `gallery`

Comment: I tried control but it is not working.

Comment: Wow @Ike you nailed it. My problem is solved , you are correct, I was not selecting the chart. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icon for "ChartLegend" is only visible/enabled when a chart is selected.

If you set visible explicitly to true it is always visible (but only enabled when a chart is selected):

`<gallery idMso="ChartLegend" size="large"  visible="true"/>`